# Can you provide a code example of a neural network and how it works on some sample inputs?

Tags: neural-network, sample

Could you give a sample of NN ?

I mean something like implemented ORC but easier.

And could you explain how does it work with examples.

Comment: Do you mean OCR as in Optical Character Recognition?  Not sure what ORC means (but then again I've been out of the research game for a while).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this site:

http://www.ai-junkie.com/ann/evolved/nnt1.html

It has an excellent explanation of Neural Networks in addition to a minesweeper program that is built using it. The original code is in C++, but there are links to ports of the code to VB.Net and Delphi.

Also check out the main page

http://www.ai-junkie.com/

to find excellent articles on genetic algorithms and Self Organizing Maps - this one is found under the Neural Network button.

Hope this helps.

Comment: woah...never seen that site before, thats awesome

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling this is not what you're actually asking but here is a simpile neural net in C#:

```
public class NeuralNode {
  double _threshold;
  double _signalReceived;
  public NeuralNode(double threshold) {
    _threshold = threshold;
    Reset();
  }
  public void Reset() { _signalReceived = 0; }
  public event Action<double> Fires = delegate {};
  public void Signal(double strength) {    
    if((_signalReceived += strength) >= _threshold)
      Fires(.5);
  }
}

var n1 = new NerualNode(1);
var n2 = new NerualNode(1);
var n3 = new NerualNode(1);
n1.Fires += n3.Signal
n2.Fires += n3.Signal
```

n1 and n2 feed into n3.  n3 will only Fire if n1 and n2 fire.

Comment: n1, n2 and n3 should all be NeuralNodes, yes?

Comment: ...yes.  And after each round you would call Reset() on each neural node.  Not the slickest implementation but the simplest.